# How to rotate an image using Flutter AnimationController and Transform?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, transform, flutter-animation

I have star png image and I need to rotate the star using Flutter AnimationController and Transformer. I couldn't find any documents or example for image rotation animation.

Any idea How to rotate an image using Flutter AnimationController and Transform?

UPDATE:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
    );
    animationController.forward();
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (animationController.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          animationController.repeat();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: new Container(
          height: 80.0,
          width: 80.0,
          child: new Image.asset('images/StarLogo.png'),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
          return new Transform.rotate(
            angle: animationController.value,
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you past code with initialization of `animationRotate`?

Comment: I update my code. Problem is that it never rotate 360 degree. It rotates about 200 or something and starts over and there is a gap they I can see it that it redraws. Having an issue to rotate 360 degree and and when stops I need to repeat without delay so I can get continues rotation whiteout stop...

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here my example of rotating image. I don't know - but maybe it suits for you

```
AnimationController rotationController;

@override
void initState() {
  rotationController = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
  super.initState();
}
//...
RotationTransition(
  turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(rotationController),
  child: ImgButton(...)
//...
rotationController.forward(from: 0.0); // it starts the animation
```

**UPD - how to solve problem with `Transform.rotate`**

In your case all works exactly as you've written - it rotates image from 0.0 to 1.0 (it's default parameters for `AnimationController`). For full circle you have to set upper parameter to 2 * `pi` (from `math` package)

```
import 'dart:math';
//...
animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 5), upperBound: pi * 2);
```

Comment: how can we add curves here

Comment: @codeboi here is answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365126/7130820

Answer (score 67):

**Full example (null safe):**

[image: Demo Screenshot]

Press "go" makes the star icon spin until you press "stop".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RotationTransition(
              turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller),
              child: Icon(Icons.stars),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("go"),
              onPressed: () => _controller.forward(),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("reset"),
              onPressed: () => _controller.reset(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Step by step guide:**

First, let your widget state class implement `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`.

Secondly, define an `AnimationController` and don't forget to dispose it. If you are not yet using null-safe, remove the `late` keyword.

```
late AnimationController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
  _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
    vsync: this,
  );
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Then wrap your `Widget` with `RotationTransition`.

```
RotationTransition(
  turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller),
  child: Icon(Icons.stars),
),
```

Finally, call methods on the `AnimationController` to start/stop animation.

- Run the animation once, use `.forward`
- Loop the animation, use `.repeat`
- Stop immediately, use `.stop`
- Stop and set it back to original rotation, use `.reset`
- Stop and animate to a rotation value, use `.animateTo`

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. I just wanted to add that if you want to add some nice animations on your rotation you could use this:  CurveTween(curve: Curves.elasticInOut).animate(_controller) and you can experiment with the effects by changing Curves.elasticInOut

Answer (score 51):

**Screenshot (Null Safe)**

[image]

---

**Full code:**

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

class _FooPageState extends State<FooPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2))..repeat();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (_, child) {
            return Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 2 * math.pi,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: FlutterLogo(size: 200),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How to rotate this along the Y axis, any ideas?

Comment: Hi, you've forgot to dispose the animation controller, which leads to 'ticker leak' exception each time the widget is disposed. Let me edit your solution...

Comment: @DmytroGierman To keep the answer small and relevant, I didn't dispose the controller.

Answer (score 4):

Here i rotate 3 images at once... images saved in assets folder... if you want you can use network images also... i am here rotate 3 images on 3 speeds...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fynd/services/auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:fynd/services/cons.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _SplashScreen createState() => new _SplashScreen();
}

class _SplashScreen extends State<StatefulWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    animationController.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: new Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash_circle3.png'))),
          child: new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animationController,
            child: new Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash_circle2.png'))),
              child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: animationController,
                  child: Container(
                      child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/images/splash_circle1.png'))),
                  )),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
                    return new Transform.rotate(
                      angle: animationController.value * 4,
                      child: _widget,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
              return new Transform.rotate(
                angle: animationController.value * 5,
                child: _widget,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
          return new Transform.rotate(
            angle: animationController.value * 6,
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

here i put the animated builder in Stack. then you can animate image rotate right(clockwise) and rotate left(anti clockwise).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fynd/services/auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:fynd/services/cons.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _SplashScreen createState() => new _SplashScreen();
}

class _SplashScreen extends State<StatefulWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    animationController.repeat();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)

    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,

      child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[

        new AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animationController,
          child :Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash_circle3.png'),fit: BoxFit.cover)),

          ),
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
            return new Transform.rotate(
              angle: animationController.value * 10,
              child: _widget,
            );
          },
        ),

       new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash_circle2.png'),fit: BoxFit.cover)),

        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
          return new Transform.rotate(
            angle: -animationController.value * 10,
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
       ),

        new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animationController,
           child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash_circle1.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            ),
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
              return new Transform.rotate(
                angle: animationController.value * 10,
                child: _widget,
              );
            }),

      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Flutter also has the widget **AnimatedRotation** [(docs)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedRotation-class.html) which makes rotating something much easier.

You only need a double to set the state of the rotation. It works in a percentage of rotation, if you turn it into degrees, it will be `0.0 = 0deg`, `1.0 = 360deg`

```dart
double turns = 0.0;
```

```dart
AnimatedRotation(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  turns: turns,
  child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
)
```

To make the rotation happen you only need to update the state, and Flutter will execute the animation automatically

```dart
void _changeRotation() {
  setState(() => turns += 1.0 / 8.0);
}
```

Full example taken from the Flutter docs to rotate the flutter Logo

```dart
class LogoRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogoRotate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LogoRotate> createState() => LogoRotateState();
}

class LogoRotateState extends State<LogoRotate> {
  double turns = 0.0;

  void _changeRotation() {
    setState(() => turns += 1.0 / 8.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _changeRotation,
          child: const Text('Rotate Logo'),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
          child: AnimatedRotation(
            turns: turns,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            child: const FlutterLogo(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
    );
    animationController.repeat();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: RotationTransition(
              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              turns: controller,
            )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 250.0).animate(_controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..addStatusListener((state) {
        if (state == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          print("complete");
        }
      });
    _controller.forward();

    new Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 5),
            () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignScreen()),
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

> full example just call
> ImageAnimateRotate( your widget )

```
class ImageAnimateRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const ImageAnimateRotate({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageAnimateRotateState createState() => _ImageAnimateRotateState();
}

class _ImageAnimateRotateState extends State<ImageAnimateRotate> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 20))..repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return Transform.rotate(
            angle: _controller.value * 2 * math.pi,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IconButton(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        icon: AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
          transitionBuilder: (child, anim) => RotationTransition(
            turns: child.key == const ValueKey('icon1') ? Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0).animate(anim) : Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(anim),
            child: ScaleTransition(scale: anim, child: child),
          ),
          child: ThemeService().isSavedDarkMode() == true ? const Icon(Icons.dark_mode, key: ValueKey("icon2")) : const Icon(Icons.light_mode, key: ValueKey("icon1")),
        ),
        onPressed: () => setState(() {ThemeService().changeTheme();}),
      ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**2023.9 Update：Now you can use `AnimatedRotation` Widget. It's much easier, no `AnimationController` is needed.**

From official docs:

```
class LogoRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogoRotate({super.key});

  @override
  State<LogoRotate> createState() => LogoRotateState();
}

class LogoRotateState extends State<LogoRotate> {
  double turns = 0.0;

  void _changeRotation() {
    setState(() => turns += 1.0 / 8.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _changeRotation,
          child: const Text('Rotate Logo'),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
          child: AnimatedRotation(
            turns: turns,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            child: const FlutterLogo(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```