# How to have a custom animation as a Flutter progress / loading indicator?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to replace the default CircularProgressIndicator with my own animation. I created a spinning widget based on the example here [How to rotate an image using Flutter AnimationController and Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745546/how-to-rotate-an-image-using-flutter-animationcontroller-and-transform) , but when replacing CircularProgressIndicator with "MyIconSpinner", for some reason it is not appearing. Any tips please?
Here are the contents of MyIconSpinner

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';

class MyIconSpinner extends StatefulWidget {
  MyIconSpinner({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyIconSpinnerState createState() => _MyIconSpinnerState();
}

class _MyIconSpinnerState extends State<MyIconSpinner>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.forward();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RotationTransition(
              turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 40,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am placing it in a widget like this

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Appbar"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: doSomething(withSomeData),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> asyncSnapshot) {
             if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData) return MyIconSpinner();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't wrap `MyIconSpinner` in `Scaffold`. You should give `MyIconSpinner` color parameter and also repeat animation after it is completed. Here is the edited version of `MyIconSpinner`.

```
class MyIconSpinner extends StatefulWidget {
  MyIconSpinner({Key key, this.title, this.color = Colors.blue}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final Color color; 

  @override
  _MyIconSpinnerState createState() => _MyIconSpinnerState();
}

class _MyIconSpinnerState extends State<MyIconSpinner>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _controller.addListener((){
      if(_controller.isCompleted){
        _controller.repeat();
      }
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.forward();
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.star,
        size: 40,
        color: widget.color,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just testing it. Getting an error "_MyIconSpinnerState#d514e(tickers: tracking 1 ticker) was disposed with an active Ticker.
"

Comment: @giorgio79 I tested and it worked fine. I cant figure out why you getting this error without the context. You can try to add `_controller.dispose()` on dispose method.

Comment: It works thanks! The issue was upstream with my FutureBuilder!