# Using for loop to create nested widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm pretty new to Flutter and have an issue of multi-nesting code of Flutter when I'm creating rotate animation. Since it's pretty repetitive, I'm trying to make it shorter with using for loop but no luck for now. Also tried to use [nested library](https://pub.dev/packages/nested) but not work. Does anybody know how? Thank you in advance.

```dart
Widget _rotateAnimationWidget(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    child: Transform.rotate(
      angle: 10 * math.pi / 180,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: 20 * math.pi / 180,
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: 10 * math.pi / 180,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: -30 * math.pi / 180,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: 0 * math.pi / 180,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: 20 * math.pi / 180,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: -30 * math.pi / 180,
                  child: Transform.rotate(
                    angle: 40 * math.pi / 180,
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                      angle: 10 * math.pi / 180,
                      child: Transform.rotate(
                        angle: 10 * math.pi / 180,
                        child: Transform.rotate(
                            angle: 30 * math.pi / 180,
                            child: child),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this nested transforms? just to be sure because nesting them won't actually animate the child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know what you want to achieve, but you can try something like the code bellow. If you check in the Flutter Inspector you will see the nested Transform. But for me isn't showing nothing in the simulator.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, is showing the container i passed as child rotated. I forgot the SizedBox. But isn't animated.

```
Widget _rotateAnimationWidget(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    List<int> angleList = [10, 20, 10, -30, 0, 20, -30, 40, 10, 10, 30];
    Widget transform;
    int i = 0;

    do {
      transform = Transform.rotate(
          angle: angleList[i] * math.pi / 180, child: transform);
      i++;
    } while (i < angleList.length - 1);

    transform =
        Transform.rotate(angle: angleList.last * math.pi / 180, child: child);

    return SizedBox(height: 200, width: 200, child: transform);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could not come up the part of `child: transform`. I appreciate it.

Comment: It's alright. But out of curiosity, how do you use this with animation?

Comment: Sorry for lack explanation. I will rotate an image back and forth in specific angles in a duration. The value of angles will be replaced with correct ones which will be implement later.

Comment: Cool! Good to know that it's possible to chain animations in this way. =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you really want to achieve that.
`Transform.rotate` turns your child widget without any animation.
I suppose you would like a rotation animation that goes back and forth?

Take a look at [RotationTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotationTransition-class.html). There is also a sample animation of the flutter logo on that website, which is quite close to what you are trying to do.

To get some code you can start with, have a look at [How to rotate an image using Flutter AnimationController and Transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745546/how-to-rotate-an-image-using-flutter-animationcontroller-and-transform)