# Flutter rotate icon on button press with animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, button, transform

I have a `button` with a `icon` inside of it. Right now I am using two different `icons` and change them `onTap`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
        _isDropdownOpened = !_isDropdownOpened;
      }
  ...
  },
  child: 
        _isDropdownOpened
            ? SvgPicture.asset(
                'images/icons/arrow_down_primary.svg',
                width: scaleWidth(12),
              )
            : SvgPicture.asset(
                'images/icons/arrow_up_primary.svg',
                width: scaleWidth(12),
              ),
  ),
);
```

This is working but I would like to have a `RotationTransition`. How can I rotate my `icon` `onTap` **with animation**, so I don't need two different SVGs?

Answer (score 2):

use `RotatedBox` widget and change its rotation in your `setState`

you can do like this

```
 child: RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: _isDropdownOpened? 2:0,
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'images/icons/arrow_down_primary.svg',
            width: scaleWidth(12),
          ),
)
```

if you want to apply animation to the rotation as well consider looking to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745546/how-to-rotate-an-image-using-flutter-animationcontroller-and-transform)

Comment: thanks! I think I wasn't quite clear. I want to have an animation for it

Comment: did you checked the link provided .. if it was helpful vote up ;)