# Flutter: Matrix4 Off-center rotation during animated transition

Tags: flutter, dart

**Description:**

Hello, I am trying to animate the rotation of an object.
For this I use Matrix4 to control the point of rotation of my object.
I have a strange behavior during the animation transition.

---

**Problem :**

Why does my green square not maintain its rotation around its center during the animation?

[image]

---

**The code :**

```
class NodeV3View extends StatefulWidget {
  const NodeV3View({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NodeV3View> createState() => _NodeV3ViewState();
}

class _NodeV3ViewState extends State<NodeV3View> {
  
  bool isExpand = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var controller = Provider.of<CompteurProvider2>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints){
            return Consumer<CompteurProvider2>(builder :(ctx , provider , child){
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => setState(() {}),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        left: 150 - 50,// => Yellow Square / 2 - Green Square / 2
                        top : 150 - 50,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              isExpand = !isExpand;
                            });
                          },
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                          transform: Matrix4Transform()
                              .rotateDegrees(
                                  isExpand == true
                                      ? 180
                                      : 0,
                                  origin: Offset(50, 50)
                              )
                              .matrix4,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              );
            });
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**Any guidance on the best way to accomplish this would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `transformAlignment: FractionalOffset.center` to the AnimatedContainer.

Comment: Thanks, I also deleted the origin in Matrix4Transform()

Answer (score 0):

i hope this one may be help you

[image]

this code for only one time rotate the box, but you will add conditions for your desire things

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TransformExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TransformExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TransformExample> createState() => _TransformExampleState();
}

class _TransformExampleState extends State<TransformExample>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController =
      AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    animationController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            animationController.forward();
          }),
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: animationController,
              child: Container(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 150.0,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                return Transform.rotate(
                  angle: animationController.value * 2.0 * pi,
                  child: child,
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to rotate it along the z-axis, a much easier way is to use the `RotationTransition` widget, check out [this existing answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55363390/1032613).

[image: 3d cube]

If you want to rotate along different axes, for example, making a 3D cube by rotating along x-axis and y-axis, you can check out this [video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDmWOsOU_Ko).

[image: 3d cube]